# jQuery ui-datepicker's calendar table width overflows ui-datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following screen shot shows a jquery ui datepicker that, up until recently, was displaying correctly:

[image: Table overflows]

The class associated with the problematic table is `ui-datepicker-calendar`, which is nested in `ui-datepicker`.  I can inspect this element in chrome and see it has a width of 100%, which erroneously confers a width of 617px, that overruns the 217px width of its parent.

I admit my inexperience with CSS, but I thought I could override the style by using something like the following snippet:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar
{
width: 217px !important;
}
```

I've seen this work in other questions on Stack Overflow, but I've been unable to fix this particular bug with like solutions to the above.  Any ideas are enthusiastically welcomed.

**Edit:**

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <br />
    <!--This div will be dynamically loaded based on the selected tab-->
    <div id="dataDisplay">
    <!-- Section table is loaded here -->
    </div>

    <!--This div will be dynamically loaded based on the selected tab-->
    <div id="mainBody">
    <!--Date picker is loaded here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
#sectionTable th, td{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#EEE;
    border:2px solid #39F;
    min-width:80px; 
    width:97%;
}
```

---

The culprit is in the above CSS entry for sectionTable.  Defining the width on this table in another div caused the symptoms in the above screen shot as Mystere Man points out.

For anyone else that stumbles across this question, check out the following resources for CSS syntax and selectors to get a better hold of your CSS file.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html
- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/slick-tables-with-css-3-selectors/
- http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Comment: add a semi colon to the end of the width: 217px !important; and also drop the space between the ! and important

Comment: Having better syntax would probably do me good in general, but unfortunately this bug didn't budge.  I'll update the question to reflect this suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, you have some style that is overriding this.  look for a th or td style with a width on it.  You may somehow be tripping over a specificity issue.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I methodically went through my CSS file and commented out each entry bit by bit, and it was a style referring to th and td.  I don't quite understand why it was overriding it yet though.  I wish I noticed your comment sooner, haha

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit was the following code that set table min-width:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
word-wrap: break-word;
/*min-width:960px;*/
}
```